# iOS fat binaries: should every arch include bitcode?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios9, lipo, bitcode

When building a library that is to be used in bitcode-enabled apps, does each arch in the fat binary need to be built with `-fembed-bitcode` or only one of them?

One of them because the bitcode is architecture-independent and will just be duplicated?

All of them because pre-processor commands may alter the code based on architecture (e.g. NSInteger width)?

Excluding x86 slices otherwise `duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline` happens?
 - [rdar://21884601](http://www.openradar.me/21884601)

Comment: Bitcode is not architecture-independent, hence each slice in a fat binary should include bitcode.

Comment: @AlexDenisov Have you got a reference for that?

Comment: Posted an answer with links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bitcode](http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html) is just another form of [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html), which is architecture-dependent.

Which means that each slice in your fat binary should contain its own bitcode section.

**Update:** I wrote a blog-post about Bitcode, you may find there some useful details: [Bitcode Demystified](http://lowlevelbits.org/bitcode-demystified/)

Comment: Where does it say bitcode is architecture-dependent?

Comment: Fair enough. Can't find it in documentation as well. But I can say for sure that's different for each slice. You can check it out manually by calling `clang -S -emit-llvm -arch arch_name main.c` using different 'arch_name' and discover LLVM IR.

Comment: I though the whole point of including bitcode was so Apple can compile it for different architectures in the future.

Comment: In fact, if you do not include bitcode for each arch, you'll get failures at archive time.